# Using ng-select with ngx-formly in Angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms, angular-ngselect, ngx-formly

I am trying to use ng-select and ngx-formly in Angular 11. I have been following the tutorials provided by the official documentation.
https://egghead.io/lessons/angular-use-3rd-party-form-controls-with-angular-formly

My current implementation is giving me the following errors:
[image]

It would be great if I could get help figuring out if I have gone wrong with the code or if I have missed any of the steps.

The below is my implementation:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { FieldType } from '@ngx-formly/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'formly-ng-select',
    template: `<div class="mat-input-infix mat-form-field-infix">
    <ng-select
       [items]= "(to.options|formlySelectOptions:field|async)!"
       [placeholder]="to.label || 'placeholder'"
       [bindValue]="to.bindValue || 'value'"
       [formControl]="formControl">
    </ng-select>
  </div>`
})
export class NgSelectFormlyComponent extends FieldType {
  formControl!: FormControl;}
```

I am using the above custom template in my main component as follows:

```
fields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
 {
    key: 'nationId',
    type: 'my-autocomplete',
    // type: 'select',
    templateOptions: {
      label: 'Nation',
      options: this.dataService.getNations()
    }
  }];
```

I have also added it in my app.module as follows:

```
FormlyModule.forRoot({
 types: [{
   name: 'my-autocomplete',
   component: NgSelectFormlyComponent,
    // wrappers: ['form-field'],
 }]
})]
```

Comment: In case of angular or other javascript questions. Adding the problem in https://stackblitz.com/  will always attract people to give answers as they can debug directly.

Comment: Did you import the component **NgSelectFormlyComponent** into your module?

Comment: @LJohnson yes I have imported NgSelectFormlyComponent in my module

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to refer the options: Observable to a component variable and call that variable from the template to load the options with Async pipe.

I also added a loaded state to render HTML after the observable has been assigned

Somehow the compiler was not able to detect its T[] | Observable as the datatypes of formly options;

Sample:

```
export class ComponentName extends FieldType implements OnInit {
    options$: any;
    loaded = false;

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.options$ = this.to.options;
        this.loaded = true;
    }

}
```

Component Template:

```
<ng-select ..>
    <ng-option *ngFor="let option of options$ | async">...</ng- 
    option>
</ng-select>
```